# Webpack: show names of module source files instead of their indexes in the bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack

In Webpack bundle each module is preceded with a comment like this:

```
/***/ }),
/* 2 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {
```

Indexes of modules in those comments are somewhat helpful when analyzing the bundle, but why not printing the source file names instead of numbers?

Is there any option that allows this?

Of course, I can go with [webpack-analyse](https://webpack.github.io/analyse/#modules), but is there any option to keep source file names right in the bundle?

Comment: Have you looked at the NamedModulesPlugin? It might not do exactly what you want to do here, but it might help: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/named-modules-plugin/